# Проблема с миграцией в Django

Tags: python, django

Возникала такая проблема, при запуске виртуальной машины, мне выдает такое сообщение:

```
You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Запустив команду `python manage.py migrate` мне показывает вот такую картину:

```
Operations to perform:

      Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, myapp, admin, contenttypes
    Running migrations:
      Rendering model states... DONE
      Applying myapp.0002_auto_20160226_1532...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_words.category_id

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.3\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
        run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
        return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
        mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:/Users/Butooz/Desktop/final\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
        executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate
        self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
        state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
        field,
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 221, in add_field
        self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
        self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 110, in execute
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
        return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Butooz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_words.category_id

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

models.py:

```
class words(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Word')
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio', blank=True, verbose_name='Audio')
    russian = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name='Russian')
    english = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name='English')
    turkish = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, verbose_name='Turkish')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Word'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Words'
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Обычно эта ошибка возникает, когда вы пытаетесь добавить к модели поле, но не делаете в нем дефолтного значения и не устанавливаете `null=True`, вот только я в вашей модели совсем не увидел поля `category`, которое есть в тексте ошибки.

Comment: @Flowneee, до этого я пытался внести изменения в модели, и как раз добавлял туда новую модель Categories, а в модель words добавлял поле category, но возникала ошибка и я решил откатиться пока не найду решение, но ошибка так и осталась.

Comment: А что за ошибка раньше была? И что вы имеете ввиду под откатиться? Возможно, неплохо бы увидеть миграции, может это чем-то поможет. Ну или если у вас текущая база просто тестовая, то снести ее, удалить сгенерированные файлы миграций и сделать заново.

Comment: @Flowneee Та же самая. Откатил, в смысле, вернулся к исходным моделям, до включения туда категорий. Да, база тестовая, так и сделал, но как быть если такое произойдет на сервере? это особенность sqllite?

Comment: Есть мысль, но не уверен что правильная: предположим, вы сначала добавили новую модель и связь. Файл миграции появился, но к базе вы ее применить не смогли, по причинам, которые я указал выше. Потом вы удалили эту модель и вернули все как было, тем самым создав еще миграцию, при этом прошлая еще не прошла, соответственно вы не сможете применить дальнейшие. Если я прав, то у вас, если посмотреть в миграции, будет сначала создание таблицы `Categories` и связь с `words`, а потом удаление этой связи и таблицы.

Comment: В будущем, если вы вдруг решили откатить изменения, просто вернитесь к устраивающей вас миграции ([тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123477/django-revert-last-migration) есть пример), ну и  можно также удалить миграцию, которая вам не нужна.

Comment: @Flowneee Спасибо за совет!